# Getting a value from a dictionary based on a value given by a list

Tags: python

I have a dictionary I.E:

```
Dict = {[A: Aardvark, Number: 1], [B: Badger, Number: 2], [C: Cat, Number: 3], [D: Deer, Number: 2]}
```

and would like the user to input a list of numbers.

I would like the code to then go through the dictionary and pull out only the animal with those numbers

So if the user inputs 2,3 the code will return

```
[B: Badger, Number: 2], [C: Cat, Number: 3] and [D: Deer, Number: 2]
```

I'm quite new to python and cannot figure out where to start with this even after doing a few searches on google (Possibly not searching for the right thing).

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The data structure you show doesn't really look like a dictionary (an unordered collection of key/value pairs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehensions, `input` function and `in` operator like this:

```py
animals = [
    {'name': 'aadvark', 'value': 1}, 
    {'name': 'badger', 'value': 2}, 
    {'name': 'cat', 'value': 3}
]

user_input = input('type in the values?')
values = [int(n) for n in user_input.split(',')]

filtered = [it for it in animals if it['value'] in values]
print(filtered)
```

output:

```
type in the values? 2, 3

[{'name': 'badger', 'value': 2}, {'name': 'cat', 'value': 3}]
```

Comment: OP wants a user input based result. So, you should modify your answer!!

Comment: @abdusco you should remove `space` after `,` from `split(', ')`  else it will throw an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,3'`.

Comment: Good catch, fixed.

Comment: Thanks all, looks like this is doing exactly what I need it to :)